# Which AWS service should I use to process large text file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a use-case where I need to read a very large text file that can contain up to 1 million records. For each record, I have to perform some validation and then transform it into a different JSON and then push it to an SNS Topic. I don't need to read them sequentially hence I can use parallelism. One option is to put the file in an S3 bucket then use a lambda to process the file which fans out (asynchronously) the records to multiple lambda functions which take care of transforming(& validation) then pushing it to an SNS. The other option is to use kinesis stream and use multiple lambdas doing the same thing. [Multiple Lambdas using kinesis streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232343/can-i-invoke-lambda-functions-in-parallel-using-a-single-kinesis-shard-if-record)

What should be the ideal way to do this?

1. S3 -> Lambda -> Multiple Lambdas -> SNS
2. Kinesis -> Multiple Lambdas (or Lambda -> Multiple Lambdas -> SNS)

Comment: What kind of format are your records? CSV? Something else? Using Kinesis is only sensible of you need some kind of ordering or will have multiple datasources, so I don't think that road is necessary.

Comment: How often will you be doing this? Is it just a one-off activity, never to be repeated? Is there any particular benefit in getting it done as quickly as possible? Do you have existing code that does the conversion (and if so, what language is it in)? How long does it take to process a record, or is it negligible compared to the I/O time? If you have an existing program that does this task (without parallel processing), how long does it take?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein. This will be a task that will be repeated once per week. No particular benefit for finishing it quickly. I have existing code (in Java). It is negligible compared to the I/O as it is just getting and setting in a new format with a few added fields in metadata. I currently do not have an existing program that does this task.

Comment: A million records isn't a large file unless each record is several megabytes long. And even then, it's well within the capacity of a single machine. And unless those records are being generated on multiple machines and aggregated, Kinesis will just add complexity. I would just write a program that runs on an EC2 instance. If you want to add scheduling, run it on AWS Batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into AWS Glue. This service can perform ETL on most of the things stored in S3, so it might save you the hassle of doing that by yourself. Combined of S3 triggering Lambda this might be an interesting option?

**Edit:**
If the file can be parsed with RegExs, perhaps try Athena? Athena is relatively cheap and can handle larger files without a hitch.

If the records have predictable length you could use Range requests get divide the file before you pass it onto Lambda, preventing long run times.

Also, have you tried parsing and chunking the file with Lambda? 1 million records isn't THAT much and simply line splitting and handing (chunks) off to a validation (or perhaps SNS) shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: S3 with lambda seems interesting but as there are lots of records (can be up to a million) and there is a limit on how long the lambda can run. Now, if S3 triggers a lambda which needs to perform transformation for every record then pushes to an SNS topic. I think the lambda than fans out this job to worker lamdas (that transforms and push) might runs out of time, even if it is doing it asynchronously. That is why I was exploring Kinesis.

Comment: But what kind of records are you handling? Is it possible to you Athena to simply query the file? Is it 1 file with 1 million records or a million files? Is serverless a requirement?

Comment: 1 file with 1 million records. And same validation and transformation for every record will be applied before pushing it to SNS.

Comment: What about S3 triggering a lambda which starts the state machine (step functions), which takes care of giving batches of records to multiple lambdas?

Comment: That could definitely work, but keep in mind Step Functions have a fixed concurrency. So if the number of records fluctuates you can't change the number of concurrent lambdas

Comment: Step functions have a limit on maximum request size is 1 MB. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html. I don't think it will work.

Comment: Why not glue? Will it not fit your requirement on file transformations, and i think it can handle a file of 1 million records?.  All transformations do it using glue, upload the transformed file to S3, and then trigger a lambda function to push the records to an SNS topic?  Will that be feasible ?